# How to get Java Decompiler / JD / JD-Eclipse running in Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler, helios, jd-eclipse

Java Decompiler (JD) is generally recommended as a good, well, Java Decompiler. JD-Eclipse is the Eclipse plugin for JD.

I had problems on several different machines to get the plugin running. Whenever I tried to open a .class file, the standard "Source not found" editor would show, displaying lowlevel bytecode disassembly, not the Java source output you'd expect from a decompiler.

Installation docs in http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse are not bad but quite vague when it comes to troubleshooting.

Opening this question to collect additional information: What problems did you encounter before JD was running in Eclipse Helios? What was the solution?

Comment: I made the steps 1, 2, 3 and the 7. and I put the folder with the class files in the project build path (right click, properties, java build path, libraries, add class folder, create new folder, advanced>>, link to folder in the file system, browse,...) then restart eclipse.

Comment: The new home of JD-Eclipse is: http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-eclipse

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's the stuff I ran into:

1) RTFM and install the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package" mentioned 
at top of the installation docs. I missed this at first because the Helios instructions are at the end.

2) Close all open editor tabs before opening a class file. Otherwise it's easy to get an outdated editor tab from a previous attempt.

3) Open the class file in the "Java Class File Editor" (not "Java Class File Viewer"). Use "Open With" in the context menu to get the right editor. If pleased with results, make it the default editor in the File Association settings, in Window/Preference General/Editors/File Associations select *.class to open with "Java Class File Editor".

4) [This guy](http://osdir.com/ml/webobjects-dev/2010-05/msg00348.html) recommends installing the Equinox SDK from the Helios update site. I did, but I'm not sure if this was really necessary. Anyone know?

5) If the class files you are trying to view are in an Eclipse Java project, they need to be in the project's build path. Otherwise, an exception ("Not in the build path") will show up in the Eclipse error log, and decompile will fail. I added the class files as a library / class file folder to the build path.

6) Drag/dropping a class file from Windows Explorer or opening it with File/Open File... will not work. In my tests, I gives a "Could not open the editor: The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput')." error. That is probably the wrong editor anyways, see 3).

7) After getting the plugin basically running, some files would still not decompile for an unknown reason. This disappeared after closing all tabs, restarting Helios, and trying again.

Comment: I would be able to execute step 5 if I could see it the the dialog window to add a library or class folder.; but I can`t. I also can't find instructions anywhere as to how to use this decompiler

Comment: The second part of step 3 was key for me in Eclipse 4.2M5. There's no Open With in the context menu, so you need to add Class File Editor under File Associations for "*.class without source" and make it the default.

Comment: I see "Class File Editor", not "Java Class File Editor". (Eclipse Indigo SR2) But choosing "Class File Editor", it still opens the old "Class File Viewer". What's wrong? Why the hell is this so difficult?

Comment: @Leo In eclipse Juno set `*.class without source` editor to `class file editor`. Changing settings for `*.class` may not work.

Comment: @Kshitiz: The problem was that the opened .class file was not in the classpath. See my Full Answer below.

Comment: +1 Got it working without step 4. However, it didn't work until I set up the association to `*.class without source`. Until then, it would just display the "org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput" error.

Answer (score 19):

To Make it work in Eclipse Juno - I had to do some additional steps.

In General -> Editors -> File Association

1. Select "*.class" and mark "Class File Editor" as default
2. Select "*.class without source" -> Add -> "Class File Editor" -> Make it as default
3. Restart eclipse

Answer (score 9):

The JD-eclipse plugin 0.1.3 can only **decompile .class files that are visible from the classpath/Build Path**.

If your **class resides in a .jar**, you may simply add this jar to the Build Path as another library. From the Package Explorer browse your new library and open the class in the Class File Editor.

If you want to decompile **any class on the file system**, it has to reside in the appropriate folder hierachy, and the root folder has to be included in the build path. Here is an example:

1. Class is foo.bar.MyClass in .../someDir/**foo/bar/MyClass.class**
2. In your Eclipse project, add a folder with arbitrary name aClassDir, which links to .../someDir.
3. Add that linked folder to the Build Path of the project.
4. Use the Navigator View to navigate and open the .class file in the Class File Editor. (Note: Plain .class files on the file system are hidden in the Package Explorer view.)

Note: If someDir is a subfolder of your project, you might be able to skip step 2 (link folder) and add it directly to the Build Path. But that does not work, if it is the compiler output folder of the Eclipse project.

P.S. I wish I could just double click any .class file in any project subfolder without the need to have it in the classpath...

Comment: Most useful answer of the bunch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo and Windows 7 64-bit:

What I did was to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package as suggested by the site and reminded by @Universalspezialist.

Then install the plugin as stated in the site: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse

Go to preference, then find "File Associations"
Click on the *.class, then set the "class File Editor" as default.

Restart Eclipse perhaps? (I did this, but I'm not sure if it's necessary or not)

Answer (score 6):

Simple thing i did to get it working:

Went in eclipse > Window > Preferences

(Optional)typed in the search box "file" to help trim the tree of options.
Went to General > Editors > File associations.

Clicked the ".class" type. Below there were 2 editors present, i clicked on the "Class File Editor" - the one with the icon from JD, clicked the "Default" button on the right.

Done.
Now all ur class are belong to us.

Answer (score 6):

After testing on Juno, Kepler and Luna, I found JD only works for ***.class files on build path**.

1. Adding the jar as a lib of an existing project
2. Go to Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations, set `*.class without source` to `Class File Editor` with a cup icon

Comment: This solution worked for me on Eclipse Oxygen. I also set "JD Class File Viewer" as the default for "*.class without source".

Comment: this solution worked for me for Eclipse 2020-03, the build path trick is necessary, Thank you !

Comment: Worked for me as well on Eclipse 2020-12

Answer (score 3):

I use jadeclipse instead, because it can't work in 3.6/3.7 eclipse

Update site
http://webobjects.mdimension.com/jadclipse/3.6/

Intallation
http://5thcross.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/installing-jadclipse-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks, I tried JD but actually the update site link is broken.

Comment: Just did this after trying and failing at everything outlined in this article. (Eclipse 2.9.2) JAD Update site works fine, Installation seems to work fine

Answer (score 3):

JAD Decomplier plug-in for Eclipse **version 3.x and 4.x.**

update site: http://feeling.sourceforge.net/update

**Steps:**

1. Open Eclipse IDE.
2. Click Help->Install New software
3. Paste above URL and give name as JAD.
4. Select the Eclipse Class Decompiler
5. Click on Next and accept agreements
6. Install it.
7. Restart Eclipse and check now.

Comment: "Document couldn't be loaded by browser" -- I almost downvoted this.  I eventually figured out that I need to put that link into Eclipse... could have been stated more clearly.  I got it installed and working, thanks!  Maybe better to reference https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jadclipse-eclipse-4x.

Comment: This works perfectly with Spring Tool Suite 3.4. Very useful for those who are facing issues with jadclipse.

Comment: Why do you post the installation steps for JADclipse, when the question is about JD-Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

if you need to decompile standalone jar try JD-GUI by the same autor (of JD-Eclipse). It is a standalone application (does not need eclipse). It can open both *.class and *.jar files. Interesting enough it needs .Net installed (as do JD-Eclipse indeed), but otherwise works like a charm.

Find it here:

http://jd.benow.ca/

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I made the steps 1, 2, 3 and the 7. and I put the folder with the class files in the project build path (right click, properties, java build path, libraries, add class folder, create new folder, advanced>>, link to folder in the file system, browse,...) then restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the  JD-Eclipse Update Site(**github.com/java-decompiler/jd-eclipse**)
2. Launch Eclipse,
3. Click on "Help > Install New Software...",
4. Click on button "Add..." to add an new repository,
5. Enter "JD-Eclipse Update Site" and select the local site directory,
6. Check "Java Decompiler Eclipse Plug-in",
7. Next, next, next... and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the site from the JD page.  I was able to install from a local site in the isntalled software section of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to add the Java Decompiler in Eclipse :

1. Open Eclipse IDE.
2. Click Help->**Eclipse Marketplace Wizard**
3. In Search tab find the JD (JD is keyword to get the Eclipse Class Decompiler)
4. Select the **Eclipse Class Decompiler**
5. Click on Install.
6. Restart Eclipse and check

Comment: Similar answer has been made before for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I used Intellij or Android studio both are working awesome for decompiling purpose.
Internally Intellij following FernFlower Decompiler.
[image]