# Java's built-in libraries implementation

Tags: java, shared-libraries, built-in

Does anyone happen to know where, if at all possible, I can take a look at the code of the java's built-in libraries?

I've tried `Ctrl + Shift + B` (which is the Netbeans' equivalence of Eclipse's `Ctrl + Shift T`) to "go to source", but I can only see the method header, and the body is always:

```
//compiled code
throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
```

For instance, I'd see the following if I tried to view String.charAt(int)

```
public char charAt(int i)
{
    //compiled code
    throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the JDK? Because you can get the source for the JDK easy as pie.

Comment: Refer to this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512066/how-to-get-java-decompiler-jd-jd-eclipse-running-in-eclipse-helios - for more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

built-in libraries source code is available with jdk. For example on a windows box the jdk folder would contain src.zip which contain the sources for the built-in libraries

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, JDK is distributed with sources, you can conveniently open them in your IDE. Look for "src.jar".

It probably already is set up. In Eclipse, just try to Ctrl-Shift-T something like "java.lang.String".

A web search will also turn up nicely linked and formatted pages.

Comment: I tried `Ctrl + Shift + B`, which is the Netbeans' equivalence of `Ctrl + Shift + T`, but I can only see the method header, where the body is `//compiled code`
        `throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");`

Answer (score 0):

Google "java decompiler" and download it. You can see the source code for any class file in the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jad to decompile any .class file