# ExtLibUtil documentation - where do you find what the available functions are?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

As I have asked questions in this form - thanks for your many helpful answers - i have found many really neat things that one can do using ExtLibUtil.???? however, other than a bit here and a bit there I have not found anything that gives a listing on the various functions. I one post I read that it is all in the source of the extension Library, and it might be if you really understand where in the source to look. Sure would appreciate a pointer and starting point.

Comment: As Paul explained, there is no documentation. Submitting this as a feedback to the OpenNTF project page would be useful. ExtLib team is very responsive on such feedbacks.

Comment: I've not seen documentation but you can see the method list in the java compiler...  That's something at least.

Comment: Install [Java decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512066/how-to-get-java-decompiler-jd-jd-eclipse-running-in-eclipse-helios) into Designer: it helped me to find some gems in libraries (like ExtLib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been unable to find a JavaDoc for it. The library slipped passed us when we wrote the book - certainly I was not as au fait with Java to be aware of it and all the strength within it. So the best option currently is to look at the source code in Eclipse. Many of the methods are helper methods to easily access things like viewScope etc, which is easy from SSJS but less easy from Java. Most are pretty self-explanatory.

Content assist doesn't seem to work from SSJS, but will from any Java class or, alternatively, open up one of the Java classes created for XPages / Custom Controls under the "local" package in Package Explorer, type "ExtLibUtil." in any method and you'll see the list.

Comment: Thank Paul will see what I can find. One of the most frustrating issues I have had in my journey into XPages has been documentation. Most of it is around somewhere but much of what I have found assumes a level of experience that many don't have. It is sort of like the key to unlock the door is there, but it on the other side of the door. The ExtLib book was invaluable, I think IBM has done a poor job of providing documentation.